# Undefined index notice in PHP while using MySQLi

Tags: php, mysqli, undefined-index

I've written this code to list data from the `utenti` table:

```
<?php 
    include("Database.php");

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM utenti";
    $rs = $conn->query($sql);

    if($rs === false){
        echo "Errore Sintassi SQL" . $conn->error;
    }else{
        $arr = $rs->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    }

    foreach ($arr as $row){
        echo "<br/>";
        echo $row['id'];
        echo "<br/>";
        echo $row['nome'];
        echo "<br/>";
        echo $row['cognome'];
        echo "<br/>";
    }
?>
```

On my friend's computer, this works perfectly; but on my computer, I get this odd notice:

> **Notice:** Undefined index: `id` in `test.php` on line 15

What could be causing it to fail on only one computer, and how can I fix it?

Comment: What does `it doesn't work` mean? What error are you getting? Do you get an error? A white screen?

Comment: Can you post a var_dump of the $rs variable from yours and your friend's computers?

Comment: undefined index of variable $row['id'] ecc..

Comment: Are you sure the `utenti` table has an `id` column on your computer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could possibly stop the undefined index error.

```
foreach ($arr as $row) {
    foreach ($row as $value) {
        echo "<br/>";
        echo $value;
    }
}
```